# IllegalArgumentExcepection when use navigation in coroutine

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I try to navigate user after job finish work so I used invokeOnCompletion and then open coroutineScope and try to navigate to another fragment. It works but my firebase crashlytics is full of crash with IllegalArguemtnExpection pointing line with navigation. Code Below

```
viewModel.confirmWz(args.order, requireContext()).invokeOnCompletion {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                        findNavController().navigate( <- this line crash
                            ConfirmWzFragmentDirections.actionConfirmWzFragmentToLoadingFragment(
                                args.order,
                                args.fullpath,
                                args.xkey,
                                args.targetList
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
```

and viewModel function look like this:

```
    fun confirmWz(order: Order,context: Context) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // send to remote 
    }
```

error log:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination ...   cannot be found from the current destination

This works but why it throws a error in logs?

Edit //
This crash only shows on Android 13

Edit 2 //
It's dont even triger catch block, just error show in firebase